# how focus a widget on screen?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I'm open a lot of widgets programmatically. So I need focus a widget when it's opened. The first time that widget it's open, automatically set focus, but the second time it doesn't.

**updated**

Code to open a widget:

```
openWidget: function (aWidgetId, searchIn) {
    var def = new Deferred();
    var wm = WidgetManager.getInstance();
    var myWidget = wm.getWidgetById(aWidgetId);
    if (myWidget == null) {

      if (searchIn === 'widgetPool') {
        wm.appConfig.widgetPool.widgets.some(function (aWidget) {
          if (aWidget.id == aWidgetId) {
            myWidget = aWidget;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });
      } else {
        wm.appConfig.widgetOnScreen.widgets.some(function (aWidget) {
          if (aWidget.id == aWidgetId) {
            myWidget = aWidget;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });
      }

      //para mostrar widgets ocultos en la pantalla
      myWidget.visible = true;
      wm.loadWidget(myWidget).then(lang.hitch(this, function (args) {
        PanelManager.getInstance().showPanel(myWidget).then(function () {
          // wm.openWidget(myWidget);
          def.resolve(myWidget);
        })
      }));
    } // end if
    else {
      myWidget.visible = true;
      PanelManager.getInstance().showPanel(myWidget).then(function () {
        //  wm.openWidget(myWidget);
        def.resolve(myWidget);
      });
    } // end else
    return def;
  }
```

Comment: might be useful to post the code you are using, easier to help when they see what they are starting from

Comment: I updated the post